# First OS preventing overwriting of memory arreas allocated to different processes?

Tags: memory, operating-systems, memory-management

recently I was asked this rather specific question: Which was the first OS that prevented a process from overwriting the memory area allocated to a different process?
I wasn't able to find an answer on this by doing some quick Googling - Someone from the class said it would have been Windows 95B, and finally the questioner answered his question by saying "Unix", but I'd be curious if someone would know about this and could provide some sources for this.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: [Much older than that.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Usage)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is wrong.

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Usage) the first OS that used memory protection
was a toss-up between :

- The [Atlas computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(computer)) commissioned in 1962 and running the [Atlas Supervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_Supervisor)
- The [Burroughs B5000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_large_systems#B5000) designed beginning in 1961 and running [MCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_MCP)

[Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) came along a decade later, being developed starting in the 1970s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Wow, that's really quite interesting. I never thought that an OS from 1961 would provide that many features as they're being listed on the Wiki page. I recently gave a very short introductory class on OS' history, and the material I used for preparing didn't even mention MCP, although I drew mainly on a standard work (which doesn't have to mean anything of course) - Then again this fact doesn't surprise me that much, if a 'standard work' describes the Comodore, Atari, Sinclair etc. OSes as "not really being OSes but merely BASIC interpreters", which is pure nonsense.